# Shader for a spotlight

Tags: opengl, glsl

How can I get this shader to have a smooth edge on the spot light instead of a hard one?  In addition, the shader has to cope with a variable value of GL_SPOT_CUTOFF.  Note that not all the lights are spot lights -- GL_LIGHT0 is a point light.

```
varying vec3 N;
varying vec3 v;
#define MAX_LIGHTS 2 
void main (void)  
{  
    vec4 finalColour;
    float spotEffect;

    for (int i=0; i<MAX_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        vec3 L = normalize(gl_LightSource[i].position.xyz - v);   
        vec3 E = normalize(-v);
        vec3 R = normalize(-reflect(L,N));

        spotEffect = dot(normalize(gl_LightSource[i].spotDirection), 
                         normalize(-L));
        if (spotEffect > gl_LightSource[i].spotCosCutoff) {
            vec4 Iamb = gl_FrontLightProduct[i].ambient;    
            vec4 Idiff = gl_FrontLightProduct[i].diffuse * max(dot(N,L), 0.0);
            Idiff = clamp(Idiff, 0.0, 1.0);     
            vec4 Ispec = gl_FrontLightProduct[i].specular 
                         * pow(max(dot(R,E),0.0),0.3*gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);
            Ispec = clamp(Ispec, 0.0, 1.0);
            finalColour += Iamb + Idiff + Ispec;
        }
    }
    gl_FragColor = gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor + finalColour;
```

}

The scene looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about attenuation, where the intensity of the light decreases as it gets farther from the center? If so, then this looks like a pretty good tutorial: http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/glsl_lighting_phong_p4.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shader from http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/glsl_lighting_phong_p3.php produces the soft edges to the spotlight you are after.

```
[Pixel_Shader]

varying vec3 normal, lightDir, eyeVec;

const float cos_outer_cone_angle = 0.8; // 36 degrees

void main (void)
{
    vec4 final_color =
    (gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient) +
    (gl_LightSource[0].ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient);

    vec3 L = normalize(lightDir);
    vec3 D = normalize(gl_LightSource[0].spotDirection);

    float cos_cur_angle = dot(-L, D);

    float cos_inner_cone_angle = gl_LightSource[0].spotCosCutoff;

    float cos_inner_minus_outer_angle = 
          cos_inner_cone_angle - cos_outer_cone_angle;

    //****************************************************
    // Don't need dynamic branching at all, precompute 
    // falloff(i will call it spot)
    float spot = 0.0;
    spot = clamp((cos_cur_angle - cos_outer_cone_angle) / 
           cos_inner_minus_outer_angle, 0.0, 1.0);
    //****************************************************

    vec3 N = normalize(normal);

    float lambertTerm = max( dot(N,L), 0.0);
    if(lambertTerm > 0.0)
    {
        final_color += gl_LightSource[0].diffuse *
            gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse *
            lambertTerm * spot;

        vec3 E = normalize(eyeVec);
        vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);

        float specular = pow( max(dot(R, E), 0.0),
            gl_FrontMaterial.shininess );

        final_color += gl_LightSource[0].specular *
            gl_FrontMaterial.specular *
            specular * spot;
    }
    gl_FragColor = final_color;
```

Comment: Sadly, this does not cope with a variable GL_SPOT_CUTOFF variable.  Question updated.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.  The above shader allows you to set the outer cone angle, which is the very edge of the spotlight and the inner cone angle which is the edge of the fully illuminated part of the spotlight and is derived from gl_LightSource[0].spotCosCutoff.  This means that the shader takes care of everything that the GL_SPOT_CUTOFF value does

Comment: I tried it and it works for only for small GL_SPOT_CUTOFF.  If that angel gets too big (>60) then the shader inverts: only the outside is lit.